# Does an Indonesian need a visa for a long layover in Korea?

Tags: visas, layovers, south-korea, indonesian-citizens

I'm Indonesian passport holder and planning to go back to Indonesia from China through South Korea. I will have a long layover of about 12 hours in Korea. Can I go outside during my layover without having a visa?